# How can I scrape instagram followers?

Tags: c#, selenium, web-scraping, instagram

there are a lot of websites where you can get a list of all followers from an Instagram profile. *For example the profile of [Jennifer Lopez](https://www.instagram.com/jlo/)*. If I click on **followers** and scroll the hole list down, I **only** see round about 1000 users. Is there any way to get a list of **all** followers, or something in the range between 10 thousand and 100 thousand users? How do the others do it?

Here are a few pages where it seems to work:

[crowdbabble](https://www.crowdbabble.com/download-all-instagram-followers/)

[Instagram Scraper](https://codecanyon.net/item/instagram-scrapper/21146630)

[magimetrics](https://www.magimetrics.com/pricing.html)

**I would be very grateful if you could help me!**

Comment: Generally, "How do I <insert broad implementation task here>?" questions don't go over particularly well on SO. If you ask a more specific question about an implementation of a follower-scraping solution, you will likely receive a better response.

Answer (score 9):

I believe most of the pages you are seeing is using the Instagram API (or the method described below). However, that is a bit hard to get access to without an application that they are happy with. As far as I have understood it, you will have to make the application before you know if you will have access, which is a bit stupid. I guess they are trying to stop new users from using it while they keep letting the people already using it keep using it.

The documentation for their API seems to be missing a lot of what was available earlier, and right now there is no endpoint to get followers(that might be something temporarily wrong with the documentation page: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/).

You could get the followers the same way the Instagram webpage is doing it. However, it seems only to work if you request up to around 5000-6000 followers at a time, and you might get rate limited.

They are making a GET request to: `https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/` with the query parameters `query_hash` and `variables`.

The `query_hash` I guess is a hash of the variables. However, I might be wrong since it will keep working even tho you change the variables. The same hash might not work forever, so its possible you would have to get the same way the Instagram page is doing it. You will get that even tho you are not logged in, so I would not think it would be very hard.

The variables parameter is an URL encoded JSON object containing your search variables.
The JSON should look like this:

```
{
  "id":"305701719",
  "first":20
}
```

The `id` is the user's id. The `first` is the number of followers you want.

The URL would look like this when you encode it. https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=bfe6fc64e0775b47b311fc0398df88a9&variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%22305701719%22%2C%22first%22%3A20%7D

This will return a json object like this:

```
"data": {
  "user": {
    "edge_followed_by": {
      "count": 73785285,
      "page_info": {
        "has_next_page": true,
        "end_cursor": "AQDJzGlG3jGfM6KGYF7oOhlMqDm9_-db8DW_8gKYTeKO5eIca7cRqL1ODK1SsMA33BYBbAZz3BdC3ImMT79a1YytB1j9z7f-ZaTIkQKEoBGepA"
      },
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The `edges` array will contain a list of node elements containg user info about people that are following the person you where searching for.

To get the next x number of followers, you would have to change the json used in the variables query to something like this:

```
{
  "id":"305701719",
  "first":10,
  "after":"AQDJzGlG3jGfM6KGYF7oOhlMqDm9_-db8DW_8gKYTeKO5eIca7cRqL1ODK1SsMA33BYBbAZz3BdC3ImMT79a1YytB1j9z7f-ZaTIkQKEoBGepA"
}
```

`after` would be what you received as an `end_cursor` in the previous request.

and your new URL would look like this: https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=bfe6fc64e0775b47b311fc0398df88a9&variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%22305701719%22%2C%22first%22%3A10%2C%22after%22%3A%22AQDJzGlG3jGfM6KGYF7oOhlMqDm9_-db8DW_8gKYTeKO5eIca7cRqL1ODK1SsMA33BYBbAZz3BdC3ImMT79a1YytB1j9z7f-ZaTIkQKEoBGepA%22%7D

This way you can keep looping until `has_next_page` is `false` in the response.

Comment: Have you any idea what the rate limits are on these endpoints? I cant see to find any documentation regarding it.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 23/08/2018**

Instagram seems to have blocked any scrolling/query hash request to get followers list/likers list on a post, at least on desktop, even for your own account.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/

It should be although still possible from a phone, maybe following a Selenium-like for mobile, using `Appmium` : http://appium.io/

Maybe some `reverse app engineering` may also be the key, if any idea from that side : 
https://www.blackhatworld.com/seo/journey-instagram-app-reverse-engineer.971468/

**EDIT 25/08/2018**

It seems to be back... if any information about it ?